# Get replies to a specific Twitter user?

Tags: twitter, rtweet, data-collection

I'm currently having trouble collecting Twitter-replies to a specific Twitter-user. I'm not trying to collect replies to a specific tweet, just the user in general (i.e. all replies to X number of tweets from a user).

I'm using the **rtweet** package and have already obtained the necessary requirements, e.g. access to Twitter API.

Is there any direct or indirect method to obtain these tweets?

Comment: You can use ```get_mentions``` to get mentions of the authenticating account, but it seems like you can't get mentions for accounts you do not own at this time.